# Shell - compare hours

Tags: shell

- Rephrasing the question :

I am sure there must be an elegant way of putting this script, but as of now here is what I can come up with for my requirement of putting a script within hourly run of cron, which will check the hour, and execute based on the VSZ variable.

Can the script be shorten up?

Timing for the script:

```
b/w 6pm-7am - restart the server
b/w 7am-6pm - send warning message
```

Here is my Script :

```
ct=`date +%H`
VSZ=3900000
# Range 1
hr1=18;hr2=19;hr3=20;hr4=21;hr5=22;hr6=23;hr7=00;hr8=01;hr9=02;hr10=03;hr11=04;hr12=05;hr13=06

# Range 2
hr14=07;hr15=08;hr16=09;hr17=10;hr18=11;hr19=12;hr20=13;hr21=14;hr22=15;hr23=16;hr24=17

# First Range
if [ $ct -eq $hr1 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr2 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr3 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr4 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr5 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr6 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr7 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr8 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr9 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr10 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr11 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr12 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr13 ] && [ $VSZ -gt '3800000' ]
then
  echo "restart"
fi

# Second Range
if [ $ct -eq $hr14 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr15 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr16 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr17 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr18 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr19 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr20 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr21 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr22 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr23 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr24 ] && [ $VSZ -gt '3500000' ]
then
  echo "notify"
fi
```

Thanks, Sue

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? Does it print nothing? Does it return an error ? What shell are you using ? So far your code sample seems to lack a `fi` to end your `if`, I don't know wether it's a typo or not. Furthermore, use a OR condition instead of a AND (a number will never be greater than 18 AND lower than 7)

Comment: What does your `VSZ` variable do ? Apart from that **your entire conditions can be replaced by the solution written by @user1328862**. I even provided  a working example to see the test in action. Just remove my `for` loop and adapt the code.

Answer (score 2):

You would need the || operator instead of the &&. I.e., the OR operator and not AND. The hour cannot be larger or equal to 18 and less than 7 at the same time.

Or, you could use a -o operator if you want.

```
if [ $ct -ge '18' -o $ct -lt '07' ]
```

Comment: This would not work for the first case scenario however: 6pm-7am

Comment: @julienc yes it would.

Comment: @Ploutox Oops, I meant the second case 7am-6pm, because `20` for instance will be after `07`, even though it is also after `18`.

Comment: @julienc We compare `$ct -lt 07`, which catches any `ct < 07` OR `$ct -ge 18` which catches any `ct >= 18`. So 20 is catched by `$ct -ge 18`, and the server will be restarted, which is the intended behaviour. `ct=7...17` won't be catched by this condition, so there will only be a warning printed

Comment: My questions is more about the comparing the hours, and not the numbers. As you know here I am comparing range of hours, and I am not sure how to compare 23 hours to be less than 07 hours. Hope you got my questions.

Comment: @SusanKoperna Not sure I get it :) To me, it seems this condition works perfectly fine for your case. Test it with `for ct in {0..23};do if [ $ct -ge '18' -o $ct -lt '07' ]; then echo "restart the server: $ct"; else echo "warning: $ct";fi;done`

Answer (score 0):

```
ct=`date +%H`
VSZ=3900000
# Range 1
hr1=18;hr2=19;hr3=20;hr4=21;hr5=22;hr6=23;hr7=00;hr8=01;hr9=02;hr10=03;hr11=04;hr12=05;hr13=06

# Range 2
hr14=07;hr15=08;hr16=09;hr17=10;hr18=11;hr19=12;hr20=13;hr21=14;hr22=15;hr23=16;hr24=17

# First Range
if [ $ct -eq $hr1 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr2 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr3 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr4 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr5 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr6 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr7 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr8 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr9 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr10 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr11 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr12 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr13 ] && [ $VSZ -gt '3800000' ]
then
  echo "restart"
fi

# Second Range
if [ $ct -eq $hr14 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr15 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr16 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr17 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr18 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr19 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr20 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr21 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr22 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr23 ] || [ $ct -eq $hr24 ] && [ $VSZ -gt '3500000' ]
then
  echo "notify"
fi
```